# Is it possible to obtain file path from IPP headers?

Tags: printing, ipp-protocol

I writeing printing web application which simulate printer behavior. It uses IPP protocol to receive document within printing request. 
I can obtain some information about print job from IPP attribute code 0x42 in  IPP headers:

- filename - full file path (it's my aim) in case of Notepad++ and only filename if I print document from MS Word
- user name - from OS

Can I obtain full file path from IPP independent from application? May be I can achieve this with additional request?

Answer (score 0):

`0x42` specifies just the value type - in this case it probably represents type `nameWithoutLanguage`.

***Filename***

Short answer: There is no standard way to obtain the file path from ipp headers.

Depending on the ipp client implementation (e.g. the windows printer driver) you might be able to use some other attributes. There are various options how a driver could submit a print job.

- Jobs sent via the ipp operation `PRINT_JOB (0x0002)`

The file is being added as stream of bytes (formatted in a specific print-job-language like postscript or pdf) . Most implementations set the job attribute `job-name` to the name of the original filename or filepath.

- Jobs sent via the ipp operation `PRINT_URI (0x0003)`

This method is rarely used but would provide a URI where the printer would have to load the file or data to print from. The URI includes a path.

***Username***

As for the username there is a standard ipp attribute available: `requesting-user-name`. It is the ipp clients (e.g. windows printer driver) responsibility to set the this value. [RFC 2911](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911) Section 3.2.1.1 Print-Job-Request says:

> The "requesting-user-name" (name(MAX)) attribute SHOULD be supplied by
> the client as described in section 8.3.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Peter. Can you suggest some PS driver for Windows, which send `PRINT_URI (0x0003)`? May be with another attribute with file path string

Comment: I am unix guy and have little knowledge about windows. It is very unlikely you find a windows driver that uses the PRINT_URI operation. Printers or print servers don't have to implement this operation because it is not a required operation. Therefore drivers usually use standard operations. Our Java implementation is capable to use the PRINT_URI operation, but that is not much help for your use case.

Comment: Peter, you said: _Our Java implementation is capable_. It's open source project?

Comment: No, the java source is disclosed so far. What programming language do you use for your implementation? please send a personal mail (see profile for contact information) for further discussion.

Comment: I'm using Java. I have seen email in your profile. I think will be better if we shall discuss questions using Stack Overflow to share our knowledge with community :)